# Xcode lost syntax highlighting and got DVTAssertions Warning for .m file

Tags: ios, xcode

My Xcode went mad just today and I can't fix it after hours searching... could anyone provide any advice?

My problem is after few minutes editing in one .m file, Xcode lost syntax highlighting and part of autocompletion for this .m file. I can observe a waring message in the console log every time when this happen. Switching to other .m file they still have syntax highlighting. Restart the Xcode can fix the problem for few minutes...

```html
15/3/6 下午5:03:22.696 Xcode[43471]:  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-6611/IDEFoundation/Diagnostic/IDEClangDiagnosticActivityLogMessage.m:184
Details:  Unable to create location for diagnostic.
mainFile: /Volumes/Disk2/Sample_project/iOS_Src/TravellerAddFbFriendsViewController.m
startLine: 4294967295, endLine: 4294967295, startColumn: 4294967295, endColumn: 4294967295
startFile: <NULL>
endFile: <NULL>

Object:   <IDEClangDiagnosticActivityLogMessage: 0x7fa4197b3140>
Method:   -initWithDiagnostic:timestamp:pathMap:workingDirectory:documentURL:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa4226b3d60>{number = 35, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

-- update 2 Jun 2015 ---

Now this happen less times since I unloaded most of plugins and use only one screen.

I have several plugins installed in my Xcode like FuzzyAutocomplete, AMMethod2Implement, CocoaPod, Auto-importer and lots of other. After upgrade to latest version of Xcode, some of them can't work due to DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs problem, I unloaded most of them and seems the problem was relieved. Now I only have Auto-Importer and will add more plugins step by step. If I find the plugin that cause this problem, will update this post again.

This issue somehow related to dual screen because it happened more often when I have a Xcode window in bigger screen for storyboard and the other window in laptop for codes.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but there seems to be a easy solution:
Deactivating Xcode Source Control in Xcode Preferences...
I haven't tried it yet and i won't try it because i need source control :(
But i hope it helps you!
You could report the bug to http://bugreport.apple.com

**Just tried it. Not working, sorry!**